# CRM 2011: Using Organization Service returns metadata reference issue

Tags: uri, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using the Organization Service URI to upload documents to our SharePoint site from notes and attachments. I'm using the code found [here](http://charlesemes.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/create-sharepoint-document-locations-in_19.html) and all is working apart from where i set the organizationURI. I get an error of "*metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved*". I have tried retyping the link in and everything i can think of but i always get this error.

The strange thing is that this was working a couple of days ago just fine, but when i tried it the next morning it refused to work and now wont do anything at all. Before this error i have now i was getting an error saying that the URI scheme is not valid. I don't know what could have caused this to stop working but i've tried all i can think of and need some help.

Thanks

EDIT: The error message has changed to "A proxy type with the name account has been defined by another assembly". Still not sure what it means, but i'm hoping this might be easier to fix

Comment: Did your service endpoints change (CRM Deployment Administrator - Server Properties)?  You should verify that you can resolve your service URL from the Settings - Customizations - Developer Resources.  I've seen similar issues when the server/certificate/DNS on the service doesn't resolve.

Comment: The error has changed again, though i'm not sure how. It now says "A proxy type with the name account has been defined by another assembly." Do you know what this means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the actual fix for this problem but i tried this and it seemed to work. So either it is the answer or i was just lucky and something else changed too, but anyway...

What i did was to change the way that i was connecting to the organization service. Before i was using user credentials, organization URI and home realm uri together to get the OrganisationServiceProxy in the form of `OrganizationServiceProxy orgService = new OrganizationServiceProxy(organizationUri, homeRealmUri, cred, null);`.

Now i'm using a longer method of first setting the discovery service with user credentials. Then together with them i set the discovery service proxy, which is then authenticated. Then i simply use a RetrueveOrganizationRequest / Response to get the organization service which i can then use in place of the original.

Hope that makes sense to people but if anyone wants i can put some code up showing what i did.